# VBA If <any of these> = <value>?

Tags: vba, if-statement, logic

I'm fairly new to VBA, and I can't find an easy way to test if any of the specified variables equal a specified value. The below seems to work, but is there an easier way to do it?

```
If variable1 = 1 Or variable2 = 1 Or variable3 = 1 Or variable4 = 1 Or variable5 = 1 Then End If
```

I've also tried the following, with no luck.

```
If (variable1 Or variable2 Or variable3 Or variable4 Or variable5) = 1 Then End If
```

Comment: For individual elements, unless there are specific properties of the variables (where bit-twiddling tricks may work), you are out of luck. For arrays, you can try running a loop... Whoops, I take it back, follow Siddharth's example below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use select case :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5

    variable1 = 1: variable2 = 1: variable3 = 1: variable4 = 1: variable5 = 1

    Select Case 1
        Case variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5
            MsgBox "One of them is equal to 1"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "none of then is equal to 1"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a serious +1, didn't ever try inverting the select case method!

Comment: I've never seen this done before. I hope I remember this trick when it will save the day.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Siddharth! Thanks for spending the time to write this answer!

Comment: But what if the value is vbNullString? That doesn't seem to work: "Invalid use of Null".

Comment: @JohnSmith *invalid use of null*? are you sure it's not a *type-mismatch*?

Answer (score -2):

A way of doing it may be using max or min.

```
If max(variable1, ..., variableN) = 1 then
```

Comment: Apart from VBA not having a `max` function, how do you see it ever working? `max(0, 1, 2)` is `2`, `min(0, 1, 2)` is `0`, neither of which are `= 1`, yet both should be true because there is a `1` in each.