# Find out if value matches any item in an array?

Tags: vba

I find myself in this situation often.

I have an array

```
Dim vArray(0 to 10) as Variant
```

and another variable

```
Dim v as Variant
```

I want to test if `v` equals any of the items in `vArray`. I know that I can use:

```
for i = lbound(vArray) to ubound(vArray)
if vArray(i) = v then
Msgbox("Found)
Exit for
end if
next i
```

But I wonder, if there any better way of doing this? Can I do it without looping?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24803580/2140173)

Comment: upvote the answers then :)

Comment: I would question what defines "better" - In terms of speed, i believe loops are still faster see [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/07/03/find-matching-data-in-array-speed-test/)